# Regular Expression for Google Analytics Goals (Require Query String Parameters)

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I'm trying to build a lookahead regular expression to match a URL, only if it has both `action=upgrade` and `result=success` as querystring parameters.

Examples to Match Against:

http://example.com/account/?result=success&action=upgrade#some_anchor

http://example.com/account/?action=upgrade&result=success#some_anchor

I tried this at Rubular, but it didn't work:

http://rubular.com/r/UmxQFkXm8z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
^https(?=.*\bresult=success\b)(?=.*\baction=upgrade\b).*
```

for testing you can try here:  http://rubular.com/r/hXYcRL1lSw I have tested your example only.